# Euler Project No. 2 with Python

Tags: python

Can somebody tell me why this should be wrong?

```
#Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated
#by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2,
#the first 10 terms will be:
#1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
#Find the sum of all the even-valued terms in the sequence
#which do not exceed four million.


sum=2

list = [1,2]
for x in range(2,100):
    a = list[x-2]+list[x-1]
    print(a)
    list.append(a)
    if a % 2 == 0:
        sum += a
        print('sum', sum)
        if sum >= 4000000:
            break
```

Comment: What is the problem when you try to run it? Do you get a wrong result? Do you get an error?

Comment: I misread this problem too (but in a different way): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736495/haskell-script-running-out-of-space

Comment: Btw the first two Fibonacci numbers are both 1 ... but that does not effect the sum of even-valued terms, of course. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

replace

```
    sum += a
    print('sum', sum)
    if sum >= 4000000:
        break
```

with

```
    if a > 4000000:
        break
    sum += a
    print('sum', sum)
```

You should compare "a" with 4000000, not "sum", like Daniel Roseman said.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a completely different way to solve the problem using a generator and itertools:

```
def fib():
    a = b = 1
    while 1:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

import itertools
print sum(n for n in itertools.takewhile(
    lambda x: x <= 4000000, fib()) if n % 2 == 0)
```

Output:

```
4613732
```

So your code, even though it is wrong (see other answers), happens to give the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

The question asked for the sum of even *terms* which do not exceed four million. You're checking if the *sum* doesn't exceed 4m.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to solve the same problem - although I understand the logic to do it, I don't understand why this works (outputs the right sum)

```
limit = 4000000
s = 0

l = [1,2]
while l[-1]<limit:
    n = l[-1]+l[-2]
    l.append(n)
    print n
```

And then then moment I put in the modulo function, it doesn't output anything at all anymore.

```
limit = 4000000
s = 0

l = [1,2]
while l[-1]<limit:
    n = l[-1]+l[-2]
    if n % 2 == 0 :
        l.append(n)
        print n
```

I'm sure this is fairly simple...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used. It is very helpful and teaches you about generators.

```
def fib():
        x,y = 0,1
        while True:
            yield x
            x,y = y, x+y

def even(seq):
    for number in seq:
        if not number % 2:
            yield number

def under_a_million(seq):
    for number in seq:
        if number > 4000000:
            break
        yield number   

print sum(even(under_a_million(fib())))
```

-M1K3

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and it should take you less than 0.1 seconds.

```
from datetime import datetime
x, y = 1, 1
total = 0
for i in xrange (1, 100):
    x = x + y
    if x % 2 == 0 and x <= 4000000:
        total += x
    y = y + x
    if y % 2 == 0 and x <= 4000000:
        total += y

print total

starttime = datetime.now()
print datetime.now() - starttime
```